# Limit the server to only respond to HTTP requests made from an iOS app - without username and password

Tags: ios, swift, laravel

I have an iOS app where the user can makes HTTP requests from their phones and the HTTP returns information based on the zip code that the user provides through the phone.

My issue is that anyone can type the URL and the server would respond with the information that corresponds to the zip code they input e.g. `http://example.com/zip-code/78515`.

My questions is, can I limit the server to only respond to requests made from my iOS app without the user having to create a user and password? In other words, if someone types `http://example.com/zip-code/78515` directly in a browser I want the server to ignore the request but if the request comes from my iOS app I want the server to respond accordingly.

For the HTTP request I'm using Laravel.

Here is my Laravel code.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('zip-code/{zipCode}', 'AppsAPIController@information');
```

**Controller:**

```
class AppsAPIController extends Controller
{
        public function information($zipCode)
        {     
            $info = CityInfo::where('ZipCode', $zipCode)->get();
            return ($info);
        }
}
```

Request:

> http://example.com/zip-code/78515

Again, the question is, how can I limit the server to only respond to requests made from my iOS app without the user having to create a username and password?

Comment: Why not just pass a token from your IOS app as part of the request or headers, then verify the token on the server before allowing a successful response?

Comment: Nothing you can do will stop a determined attacker - they can construct a request that's indistinguishable, given enough technical know-how. There may be "good enough" solutions that deter casually curious non-technical users.

Comment: @matticustard I was thinking about something like that, but I wasn’t sure if that was possible without using authentication. I’ll try to find more info on how to use tokens. Thanks!

Comment: @ceejayoz - I don’t have any sensitive information, I just don’t want to overload the server with unnecessary requests. What would be potential problem I could run into if I leave it open without any verification? Thanks

Comment: There are full-blown solutions like Passport that can handle token based authentication.  But if this is all you need it for, I would just set a random token in your **.env** file (e.g., `MY_IOS_TOKEN=m43t7hmg7t435cmg85t3c7`), append the same token to your IOS app requests, then validate the received token within your controller.  Easy and done.  Should be plenty to stop random requests for non-sensitive data.

Comment: Do you really have an issue? Are there people hitting the urls from different browsers now? Maybe do nothing till its a problem, the "fix" is trivial but I assume you have better things to do

Answer (score 1):

This package seems to do that

https://github.com/spinen/laravel-browser-filter

Basically, you are adding a middleware that reads the user agent out of the request, and denies the rest.

Comment: Be aware that this is pretty trivial to defeat

Comment: The request will be done in code from the app not from a browser.

Comment: That doesn't really matter - requests can be made from anywhere, user agents can be spoofed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no foolproof way to respond only to requests made by your app.

User agent sniffing, navigator feature detection, and like measures may deter most basic attempts to load information from that url (like search engine bots), but anyone with a little time can learn to replicate the HTTP requests made by your app, defeating those measures.

Even requiring a login will not prevent external request (they can send requests matching your login workflow to obtain a valid token, then request the restricted url with it).

Comment: @ Barnyard - Thank you for the info. So, would you say that if there is not sensitive information leaving the request without any authentication would be ok? What would be the potential problem if I leave it without authentication?

Comment: @fs_tigre Some things I can think of:  1. If you are paying for that information (comes from a paid API or something), then someone taking it without paying for your app (or seeing the ads in a free app) would be a concern.  2. A shady developer taking your api to power their own app.  3. If responding to the request takes significant computational resources and your server cost varies by usage.

Comment: Also I am not saying some request verification is not worth it, just be aware that a determined individual can bypass it.

Answer (score 1):

> (via the comments) I just don’t want to overload the server with unnecessary requests.

In that case, there's a much better solution. Laravel ships with a `throttle` middleware, which you can use to limit the number of requests per minute per IP (or per logged-in user, if they're authenticated).

Just add `throttle:60,1` to your route's middleware and it'll max out at 60 requests per minute for a particular IP address. Set it to something relatively high (so normal use doesn't hit it), but it'll prevent millions of requests from the same IP from using up too many resources.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Throttling in Laravel.